# Magento 1.7*: How do I add "Logout"-link in the sidebar, of my-account-page

Tags: xml, magento-1.7

I would like to add a "logout" link to a Magento shop, that i am developing.

In the page "My account", left sidebar under all the links (last link at the bottom):

- Account Dashboard
- Account information
- Adress book
- Etc.

How do I add a link at the bottom?

I think that I should add a line of code in customer.xml.

I guess it should be in this block:

```
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
```

And something in the line of:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>LOGOUT</name><path>LOGOUT_PATH</path><label>Logout</label></action>
```

I'm just not sure what the exact code should be.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out.

The code was:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>logout</name><path>customer/account/logout/</path><label>Log out</label></action>
```

Answer (score 9):

While your solution works, it is considered best practice to make all layout changes within the file `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml` and refrain from editing the other layout files directly.

For this change, your local.xml would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <customer_account>

        <reference name="left">

            <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
                    <name>logout</name>
                    <path>customer/account/logout/</path>
                    <label>Log Out</label>
                </action>
            </reference>

        </reference>

    </customer_account>

</layout>
```

**local.xml Reference**

A good resource to start using local.xml is on this page:
[Classy Llama's Better Way to Modify Magento Layout](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout)

Article would be better without the word wrapping but they cover most of the means of editing your layout.